# Parameter not passed to controller - Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I am at wits end here. This seems a very trivial thing but its not working. I have a jsp page that passes back to the server a Long (tournamentId) and a list of Objects.
When I post the form, the list is passed properly, but the Long member comes back as null, even though I can see it was sent.

The jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addBets" modelAttribute="gwbCollection">
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${gwbCollection.tournamentState == 'CLOSED_FOR_BETS'}">
        <br>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
<input name="tournamentId" value="${gwbCollection.tournamentId}" type="hidden"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Side A:</td>
            <td>Score A:</td>
            <td>Side B:</td>
            <td>Score B:</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="gwb" items="${gwbCollection.games}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td><input name="games[${status.index}].game.gameId" value="${gwb.game.gameId}" type="hidden"/>
                    <input name="games[${status.index}].userId" value="${gwb.userId}" type="hidden"/>
                    <input name="games[${status.index}].game.tournamentId" value="${gwb.game.tournamentId}" type="hidden"/>
                    <input name="games[${status.index}].bet.betId" value="${gwb.bet.betId}" type="hidden"/>
                    ${gwb.game.sideA}</td> 
                <td><input name="games[${status.index}].bet.scoreA" value="${gwb.bet.scoreA}"/></td>
                <td>${gwb.game.sideB}</td> 
                <td><input name="games[${status.index}].bet.scoreB" value="${gwb.bet.scoreB}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${gwbCollection.tournamentState == 'OPEN_FOR_BETS'}">
            <input type="submit" />
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</form:form>
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class BetController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBet(@ModelAttribute("gwbCollection") GamesWithBetsCollection gwbCollection) {
    List<Bet> bets = gwbUtil.getBets(gwbCollection);
...
}
```

And finally, GamesWithBetsCollection:

```
public class GamesWithBetsCollection {
private TournamentState tournamentState;
private Long tournamentId;
private List<GameWithBet> games;

public GamesWithBetsCollection() {

}

public List<GameWithBet> getGames() {
    return games;
}

public void setGames(List<GameWithBet> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

public TournamentState getTournamentState() {
    return tournamentState;
}

public void setTournamentState(TournamentState tournamentState) {
    this.tournamentState = tournamentState;
}

public Long getTournamentId() {
    return tournamentId;
}

public void setTournamentId(long tournamentId) {
    this.tournamentId = tournamentId;
}
```

}

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference but I notice your setter for `tournamentId` is expecting a `long` but your field and getter specify a `Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nickdos - WOW! That is the answer! Beautiful catch!

To recap - the field "tournamentId" is defined as Long (object), but the setter has long (primitive) as parameter. Changing it to Long(object) did the trick.

Thanks again Nickdos!